# HTML - Make div parent inherit div child height

Tags: css, html

I'm having problems to make the div parent inherit the height of the div child.

[image: Problem]

```
.parent {
        position: relative;
    }

.child {
        position: absolute;
        width: 960px;
    }
```

The text should be in the black gap.

Any help?

Comment: Try to remove position: absolute from child style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the child to be positioned absolutely for some reason?
This is why it doesn't 'fit' in your parent element.

According to the documentation

> Position absolute:
>   Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

View the illustrations at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position to see what exactly happens.

Answer (score 2):

Remove any size attributes of the parent, it will then become as big as it needs to be for its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you declared position:absolute? If you want to move .child you should use position:relative or margins.

Absolute positioning removes the element from the natural flow of the document.